# I am not able to find antix base iso

Tags: linux, ubuntu, distributions, antix

I am only able to find the iso for full version but not base or even core.
I searched on net but couldn't find any information more over the antix web site page is not of any help

Also, can someone please help me with what is the difference between full,base and core.

thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to https://antixlinux.com/download/

Next, select your country, or follow one of the CDN links. This will guide you to the iso downloads. You will find there the links for net, core, base and full images, for both 386 and x_64.

Example direct link to [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/antix-linux/files/Final/antiX-19/)

The different versions you can download:

- **full**: Includes (almost) everything. If packages are missing, they can be installed later. This is the biggest initial size to download, and probably the best choice if in doubt.
- **base**: Includes only the most often used packages, to keep the image small. If packages are missing, they can be installed later. Benefit is smaller image size.
- **core**: Includes the minimum set of packages needed for installing the system. If packages are missing, they can be installed later. Benefit is even more reduced image size.
- **net**: Includes only the installer. Missing packages to have a running systems will be downloaded during installation. If packages are missing, they can be installed later. Benefit is smallest possible image size.

Comment: i might cry now......Thankkkkkk you Sooooo much. Also i feel much more dumb now.

Comment: No worry and welcome. Sometimes it just happens that one does not see some things...

Comment: @xzel If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.